# Can you make a queryselector to look for an element by attributes but also not containing a certain class name?

Tags: javascript, html, css, queryselector

So let's say I have some elements like these:

```html
<div class="a b" data-one="1" data-two="2"></div>

<div class="c" data-one="1" data-two="2"></div>

<div class="b" data-one="1" data-two="2"></div>
```

Now I want do get all the divs NOT containing className `b` and `data-one="1"` and `data-two="2"`. How should I do that? Thanks!

Comment: something like div.b[data-one=1][data-two=2]

Comment: @CoderLee - Well, the meaning of the question was changed, invalidating the first answer. Even now, it's open to interpretation which properties the NOT is intended to apply to. We also have no attempt by the OP to solve it themselves, nor any indication of research they have conducted.

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
document.querySelectorAll('div:not(.b)[data-one="1"][data-two="2"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```js
$('div:not(.b)[data-one="1"][data-two="2"]')
```

Using vanilla JavaScript `querySelectorAll`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div:not(.b)[data-one="1"][data-two="2"]')
```